# Comparing [tag:comparative-review] to a regular review

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, comparative-review

> I think that a comparative review should be 2 questions, and then the user can take the answers from both and do the comparing on their own. then they can decide what is going to work best for their situation.

[This came from chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23279364#23279364)

There is a lot of discussion in Chat about [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review)s and whether or not they are good questions.  The above was my response to the discussion this morning.

We can't make the decision for the user on whether one or the other is going to be a better fit for their application.

I think that we need to take another look at this tag and make a decision what we should do with it

Answer (score 9):

We've seen in increase in people interested in which code is better for a certain task, without being interested in a review of the code itself. I think that's a problem.

To quote [Malachi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23279364#23279364):

> I think that a comparative review should be 2 questions, and then the user can take the answers from both and do the comparing on their own. then they can decide what is going to work best for their situation.

The problem is that the main point of this SE is reviewing code. Reviewing, not answering specific programming problems like "How should I do this?". That's Stack Overflow.

I think the reason the tag still exists is because it can be reworded to "This is what I have, is it better than the alternative I also mention?". But those offering such an alternative in the question itself are often not interested in critique on the rest of the code.

I can not see a reason why offering an alternative is even a good idea. If you're interested in the pro's and con's of both versions, make it two posts. Offering an alternative is very much steering answers into the direction you want it to go. That's not how reviewing works!

As [I said in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=23240040#23240040) not too long ago:

> Code Review is not about what you need. It's about what you get.

Questions should be looking for [feedback about any or all facets of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The moment you post it, it's hunting season. Reviewers can shoot at any and all parts of the code. Reviewers should not be expected to just pick one of the provided alternatives and say why it's better.

If we consider the tag on-topic after all, we may need some additional constraints when that tag is used.

This discussion recently got hot after [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/99253/52915), but that's not necessarily the best example of why the tag is problematic.

Comment: `Code Review is not about what you need. It's about what you get.` ++ Awesome quote.

Comment: Whilst I think comparative reviews should stay. I agree heavily with most of this answer. Posts that don't want a review should not be allowed here, but since we can answer them they're not off-topic so we waste answerer's time on futile questions. I would prefer a "Doesn't want a review" reason as I've seen quite a few non-review questions of late (without being a comparative review).

Answer (score 5):

I think that we should require users to post their (*working*) code in two separate questions.

Then the user can take the answers they receive from both questions and make a decision themselves on which is going to be a better fit for what they are doing on a larger scale.

These questions should be linked, create both questions then edit a link into them from the other one.

doing it this way we could still tag it with [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) so that reviewers know that there is another version to look at.

Comment: I agree that many (most?) of these questions should rightfully be two posts, I'd personally love to just see that tag burn.